# ZoomTo boundingBox in SearchBox.onSelect with HERE maps and place

Tags: javascript, zooming, here-api, search-box

I am using **nokia.places.widget.SearchBox** together with **nokia.maps.map.Display**.

You can use onSelect function of the SearchBox to perform operations when a user picks an items from the results list.

What I need to do is center and zoom the map to the picked place. My problem is concerning zooming because I don't know what level to use.

I noticed that some places have boundingBox (to use with the **zoomTo** function of the Display component) property but other doesn't. I could use category (*'administrative-region'*, *'street-square'*, etc.) but it is other than precise and moreover I can't find a list of possible category codes.

Any suggestion?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get the map to move/zoom to a location when a suggestion is  chosen, you will need to implement an `onResults` handler:

```
var fromSearchBox = new nokia.places.widgets.SearchBox({
    targetNode: "fromSearchBox",
    template: "fromSearchBox",
    map: map,
    onResults: function (data) {
        // Your code goes here //

    }
});
```

As you noticed the `data` field may or may not hold a bounding box. This is because only a few locations cover a defined **area**, most are **point** addresses.

For the subset which have a boundingbox you can do the following:

```
if (data.results.items[0].boundingBox){
    map.zoomTo(data.results.items[0].getBoundingBox());
}
```

For the remainder the answer will depend upon what you are trying to achieve, but you could try any of the following:

- Move to the location on the map without altering the zoom. (i.e. let the user decide)

  ```
  map.set("center", data.results.items[0].position);
  ```
- Move to the specified bounding box for a point object at  the
  specified location.

  ```
  var obj = new nokia.maps.map.StandardMarker(startPoint);
  map.zoomTo(obj.getBoundingBox());
  ```

Or alternatively: `map.zoomTo(nokia.maps.geo.BoundingBox.coverAll([startPoint]));`

- Define a bounding box surrounding the point location and zoom to that instead

  ```
  startPoint =data.results.items[0].position;
  bottomLeft = new nokia.maps.geo.Coordinate(startPoint.latitude - 0.1,
           startPoint.longitude + 0.1);
  topRight = new nokia.maps.geo.Coordinate(startPoint.latitude + 0.1,
           startPoint.longitude - 0.1);
  map.zoomTo(nokia.maps.geo.BoundingBox.coverAll([topRight, bottomLeft]));
  ```

Additionally, [Display.zoomTo()](http://developer.here.com/docs/maps_js/topics_api_pub/nokia.maps.map.Display.html#topic-apiref__Display-zoomTo) can also take an additional parameter, so if you use  `map.zoomTo(BoundingBox, true)` you will also keep the current center for the map on screen, and this may give more context to a user.

Comment: I think I will use the coverAll static method, thank you @JasonFox!